# Python Hatch: `ERROR: Package 'hatch-demo' requires a different Python: 3.10.5 not in '<3.10,>=3.9'`

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, python-packaging, hatch

```bash
hatch new "Hatch Demo"
cd hatch-demo
```

In pyproject.toml, I set:

```ini
requires-python = ">=3.9,<3.10"
```

I run:

```bash
hatch env create
```

I get:

```
ERROR: Package 'hatch-demo' requires a different Python: 3.10.5 not in '<3.10,>=3.9'
```

I have both Python 3.9 and 3.10 installed via Homebrew. Python 3.9.13 is set as the default.

```bash
python3 --version
Python 3.9.13
```

How do I fix this so that Hatch will use Python 3.9.x when creating the environment for this project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way it works with hatch (as far as I understand) is that the (default) environment is configured independently from the project requirements (those are for building the packages sdist/wheel/...). By default it will use the first python interpreter found on your $PATH ([according to this](https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/plugins/environment/virtual/)), which I'm guessing is 3.10.5 in this case. This is independent of the python executable hatch itself is run with.

The solution then is to tell hatch in the `pyproject.toml` which python version to create the `default` environment with [as described in the official docs](https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/config/environment/overview/#python-version):

```ini
[project]
name = "myproject"
requires-python = ">=3.9,<3.10"
...

[tool.hatch.envs.default]
python="3.9"  # <--

# other optional environment configuration, e.g.
path = ".venv"
dependencies = [
  "black",
  "pytest",
  ...
]
```

For this, the requested version needs to be installed on the system. It can also be an absolute path to the python executable.

Then issuing a `hatch env create` or a `hatch run myfile.py` should create a virtual environment with the correct python version, project dependencies and the virtual environment dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to force the python interpreter with which hatch is executed (and which I would hope is then used for the env) like this:

```
/full/path/to/python.310 -m hatch env create
```